# Logistic regression for repeated measures

Tags: logistic, correlation, kendall-tau

I have data corresponding to reports of "mind wandering", i.e. thinking about something unrelated to the task, and I want to look at the link between these reports and trust (regarding a system capability). For each subject, I have 25 values of mind wandering (binary variable) and trust (range between 1 and 5).

I firstly used a Kendall rank correlation, however someone told me that it would not account for repeated measures. That same person told me to use logistic models.

I am not entirely sure that looking at logistic models would tell me the same thing as correlation test. However I have never done logistic regression, and so I am a bit lost with the possibilities offered by the technic. Is there a possibility to make correlations accounting for repeated measures?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can separate the  subject data samples and compute the means, then calculate the correlations between the means.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I agree that this would solve the problem, however I think it would lower the sharpness of our test by aggregating (and therefore loosing) much data.

Comment: Have you tried the split-plot ANOVA, what about MANOVA and /or Mixed models approached

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, as I explain in the original post, I don't know if the results would be similar to a correlation. For example, if I have a significant predictor in my mixed effect model, I can say that this predictor influences my dependent variable (and only linearly). However can I say that my variable and my predictor are correlated? I don't think so.

Comment: If the predictor can directly  and linearly influence the dependent variable , then correlation exists. Only check the magnitude

Comment: I agree with you on that, however a correlation can also exist without linear influence (e.g. a quadratic relation would be revealed by a correlation test, but not by a linear model).